# Repeating Chart in SSRS?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I'm working on some reports in SSRS 2005.  I have a bit of experience of SSRS, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to do this.

The report pulls in a data set from a stored procedure.  Then I basically want to generate a Pie Chart for each row in the dataset.  How on earth can I make the chart control repeat n times?  is it even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the chart in a tablix.

Comment: I didn't think I had tablix in 2005, I appear to be able to put it in a Matrix, looks like we're on to something here...

Answer (score 0):

You could create multiple charts and with each, add a filter.  That's all I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gabriel.  I didn't want to create multiple, but using the matrix appears to do the trick.